# numpy concatenate two matrices . TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: numpy

I performing following operation:

```
matrix_a = np.concatenate(matrix_a, matrix_b)
```

both matrices type is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

shapes of matrices are:

```
(26, 127)
(67, 127)
```

The operation throws following error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can someone explain why i get this error and how to fix that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fixed.  Matrices should be a tuple:

```
matrix_a = np.concatenate((matrix_a, matrix_b))
```